# Why isn't our Runtime updating with `set_code`

Tags: runtime, runtime-upgrade

We've gone through the [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/forkless-upgrade/) for running upgrades. We've been able to successfully upgrade using the Polkadot UI.

However, when we do the same thing with our custom Runtime, although the tx says it's added to block, the version doesn't get bumped. i.e. the upgrade isn't successful.

On investigation of the block with the included tx, we find this event:

```
Unable to decode storage system.events:: createType(Vec<EventRecord>):: Vec<EventRecord>:: Decoded input doesn't match input, received
0x0c020c0500000000000000005095a20900000000020000000100000000010305000000000000000000010000 (44 bytes), created 0x0c020c0500000000000000005095a20900000000020000000100000000010305000000000000000000010000000000 (47 bytes)
```

This event error isn't helping us understand what we're doing wrong.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be different about our Runtime that could be causing this? Or, is there a way that we could get more information about what's going wrong?

I'll note that our Runtime is on `3.0.0` and the tutorial code we're running is on `4.0.0-dev`.

Thanks!

Update:

Another strange thing: we wanted to get insight into how far into the `set_code` call it was getting, so we pulled down the source code for `frame-system-3.0.0` and patched our dep in `cargo.toml`. We then have tried adding events and even panics to the call code... but the behavior doesn't change. If we try compiling with bad code it breaks, but other than that it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: What's  your custom runtime? If there is code that would be much easier to debug.

Comment: Wish I could share it... this isn't public code yet.

Comment: Did you bump the spec version? Did you change anything other than the runtime? if so you might need to compile your validators RPC nodes to the newest release.

Comment: We definitely bumped the spec version. And if we didn't we would expect to get an error, but the UI is saying it's successful. I'm not sure if we are compiling our validators RPC nodes... we are only changing the runtime for now though. Trying to do this incrementally.

Comment: Could you try updating to a newer substrate version? 3.0.0 was released 1.5 years ago and lots of things has changed since then.

Comment: Which version do you recommend? 3.0.0 is the last "stable" version, at least according to the GitHub. I assume it's still supported. I guess crates.io says 6.0.0 for a lot of them.

Comment: The last 'stable' version would be the `polkadot-v0.9.28` tag from GitHub. Substrate release have not been properly published (i.e. GitHub or crates.io releases) since quite some time.

Comment: I understand you would rather not share your code. Are you able to share your runtimes or a RPC node ?